# adding epsilon in entropy calculation

Tags: matlab, entropy, epsilon

Using some mathematical tricks and MATLAB, we can easily calculate the entropy of given input. For instance

```
x = [10 25 4 10 9 4 4];
[a,b]=hist(x,unique(x));

x =

    10    25     4    10     9     4     4

a =

     3     1     2     1

b =

     4     9    10    25
```

My question is the following: Because we are using log function, is it advised to add a small constant within the logarithm function to ensure proper calculations?  For instance, should we use `+eps`?  As an example:

```
probbailities=a./numel(x);

probbailities =

    0.4286    0.1429    0.2857    0.1429

-sum(probbailities .*log2(probbailities));

ans =

    1.8424

-sum(probbailities .*log2(probbailities+eps));

ans =

    1.8424
```

Comment: sorry instead of sum,i should divide it by length,but it does not matter in this case

Comment: Since in your edit you remove your question. There nothing here to answer. But `log2(0) = -Inf`. So yes, to avoid trouble epsilon can be a good idea. Because with numerical imprecision, you will lost some information. But if you work with 4 digit, it enough with eps.

Comment: but is it adviced because we are using log function,use +eps inside logarithmic function? it is question sir

Comment: If you probability is zero, it sound like your element isn't suppose to be taken. So, you should just not sum on it. Epsilon avoid log2 infinity. But normaly, You shouldn't have prob = 0.

Comment: Take example of word count, If your word appear with 0 probability. This word isn't needed in your set. So don't need to compute a prob for it. So your entropy estimation shouldn't take this element. So log2 isn't suppose to have 0 in it. So no problem. And probability should sum to 1. And in case of 1 value, prob = 1 and log2(1) = 0. Entropy of 0 is good for one element, you have no restriction with other elements.

Comment: You can maybe read the [coin toss example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) to understand that the probability is between 0 and 1. That show H(x) is a parabolla in that case.

Comment: @AlexandreBizeau  have a nice night,thanks for your efford

Comment: When I have calculated joint image entropy, I usually skip over any probability bins that have 0.  What I do is I find any locations in the PDF that have 0 and just skip those in the sum.  Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691398/mutual-information-of-two-images-matlab

Comment: but i can't see  reason of downvoting

Comment: @datodatuashvili I didn't downvote.  This is a legitimate question.  However, your phrasing about whether or not to add a constant to ensure the proper domain was not very clear in the question.  I have modified your phrasing to reflect this.